# Angular expressions in $watch trigger twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does this `$watch` fire twice when a simple comparison is passed as the watchExpression?

```js
$scope.foo = 0;  // simple counter

$scope.$watch('foo > 4', function() {
  console.log("foo is greater than 4: ", $scope.foo);
});
```

The listener fires when the page loads, when `foo` is `0`, then once more (and only once more) when the value of `foo` goes above 4.

Why does the listener fire when the page loads? And why doesn't it continue to fire when `foo` is greater than 4?

I set up a simple plunkr to show what's happening: http://plnkr.co/edit/ghYRl9?p=preview

Answer (score 23):

After re-reading the [Angular $watch docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch) a few more times, I think I understand what's happening.

> The listener is called only when the value from the current watchExpression and the previous call to watchExpression are not equal

Angular tracks the value of the watchExpression `foo > 4` with each `digest()` loop. Because this evaluated to false until `foo` was greater than 4, the listener didn't fire. Likewise, after `foo` was greater than 4, the values Angular was comparing were both true. The only time it detected a change was when the evaluated expression crossed over.

Two values are passed to the `$watch` listener function, the new value and the old one. Logging these values shows that the watchExpression is being evaluated, and Angular is looking for a change in those values.

```js
$scope.$watch('foo > 4', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  console.log("foo is greater than 4: ", $scope.foo, oldVal, newVal);
});

// foo is greater than 4:  5 true false
```

The reason the listener was called on page load is also documented:

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the `listener` fn is called asynchronously (via `$evalAsync`) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of `watchExpression` didn't change. To detect this scenario within the `listener` fn, you can compare the `newVal` and `oldVal`. If these two values are identical (`===`) then the listener was called due to initialization.

I updated the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ghYRl9?p=preview) with a second `$watch` that evaluates the value of `foo` internally:

```js
$scope.$watch('foo', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if ($scope.foo > 4) {
  console.log("foo is greater than 4: ", $scope.foo, newVal, oldVal);
  }
});

// foo is greater than 4:  5 5 4
// foo is greater than 4:  6 6 5
// foo is greater than 4:  7 7 6
```

Comment: Just to add to this, I find evaluating your specific conditional (> 4) is always better *inside* the `$watch` callback (as you have in your last code snippet) because it is often valuable to be able to check whether the `$scope` property actually has a value (`newVal != null`) and if it changes (`!angular.equals(newVal, oldVal)`).

Comment: As Terry stated.  What I used to check an object on the $watch listener so that it doesn't fire multiple times on init is:

if(newVal != null && (!angular.equals(newVal, oldVal))) {
    console.log('object changed');  
}

Only fires when form / object updated after initial load.

Comment: One small note; please use !== instead of != JSLinters will thank you.