# Angular scope watch fires twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a watch set up to track when a property in my service changes. When the property changes, i need to make an AJAX call to a webservice, however, when the property DOES change, the watch is firing twice. I have tried checking newValue !== oldValue but when I log their respective values to the console, the first time the watch fires it look like this:

```
newValue: MyObject, oldValue: undefined
```

and then when it fires immediately after, they are identical to the first time:

```
newValue: MyObject, oldValue: undefined
```

The problem this causes is that 2 AJAX calls get made instead of 1. How do I get the watch to fire the function once?

Comment: Could you provide some more information, e.g. the code of the $watcher as well as the ajax-call?

Comment: Please provide your code, maybe it has his own watcher and you adding another watcher on that

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment that the $watch listeners will fire upon initialization if it is tied to a $scope variable.  You would need to add a conditional within your $watch listener to look for 'oldValue === newValue' to know if it was caused by initialization or not.  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942930/angular-expressions-in-watch-trigger-twice/20942931#20942931)  Based on your question this doesnt seem to be your problem, but just wanted to point that out.